# Sqlalchemy search JSONB column with arrays and no keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to filter a JSONB column in flask-sqlalchemy and am having trouble:

```
class Journal(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    synonyms = db.Column(JSONB)

j = Journal(synonyms=['red', 'blue'])
db.session.add(j)
db.session.commit()

records = Journal.query.filter(Journal.synonyms.contains('red')).all()
```

I get the error: `sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction) current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the correct query for this. It is:

```
import json
records = Journal.query.filter(Journal.synonyms.contains(json.dumps('red'))).all()
```